# Meshes have missing/transparent faces after applying an explode modifier?

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to apply an explode to an object. I have set the start point for the particles at frame 25 but this leaves my mesh in a fractured state prior to the explode with seeming missing or transparent faces in places.

I have checked the normals and searched the internet looking for a clue... any help?

Latest blender 2.8 windows 10 install.

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! Does your animation also start on frame 25? If so, that will cause issue. If not, could you upload your blend file so we can take a quick look? You can upload it here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ Otherwise screenshots of particle/modifier settings would be helpful too.

Comment: Hi mate. wont let me upload as the file is over 30mb's

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6776

Comment: sorry i just quickly remade the file without materials.. if i remove the remesh modyfier the entire front face is missing?

Comment: Hi sorry lol.. I just sent another file.. Simple standard cube.. subdivided to 50.. applied explode and now 2 faces are missing/transparent?

Comment: The link is only to the download button image, not the actual download link. At the bottom left of your question there is a small edit button. Click that to edit your post. When you upload your blend it will show you some text to include in your question. Copy paste that text into your question and save the edits. Then I will be able to download it.

Comment: Its ok! I managed to find a work around to stop the affect happening. I had to delete all automatically generated materials and textures from the quick explode function and then setup new ones.. this immediately solved the issue. thanks guys! x